# How can I generate unique names for my plots generated in a loop, so they don't end up overwritting one another?

Tags: r, bash, shell, loops

I am currently trying to run a bash script along with an R script in the Linux "cartesius surfsara" environment. The goal of the script is to get an idea of the contents of a large array of files. I look at the structure of the files, a summary of specific columns, and try to plot them. The plotting is where my problem lies, I am unable to generate unique plot names. Therefore, the plots generated overlap one another and only two plots are generated in the whole process. Any help regarding this problem would be much appreciated!

This is the bash script in which I call the R script

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH -t 2:10:00

module load 2019
module load R

#copy files
cp  $HOME/Donders/Brain_volumes/*.gz $TMPDIR

cp $HOME/Donders/plotting.R $TMPDIR 

#go into scratch
cd $TMPDIR 

ncors=15
for file in *.gz; do 
((k=k%ncors)); ((k++==0)) && wait
{
  Rscript plotting.R $file --no-save --slave --quiet
} &
done
wait

#copy files back to homedir 
cp *.csv $HOME
cp *.png $HOME
```

This is the R script where I plot the contents of multiple files, however, only 2 plots are generated at the end of the loop because I do not generate unique names and they overlap one another.

```
#load libraries
library("R.utils")
library("data.table")

A=commandArgs(trailingOnly=T)[1]

#read in data
data <- read.table(A, header = TRUE)
 
b <- as.numeric(data$beta) 
se <- as.numeric(data$se)

str(data)

summary_dat <- summary(data) 


png(filename = "b.png", 
    width = 640, height = 480, units = "px", pointsize = 12, 
    bg = "white", res = NA, 
    type = c("cairo", "cairo-png", "Xlib", "quartz"))
hist(b)
dev.off() 

png(filename = "se.png",
    width = 640, height = 480, units = "px", pointsize = 12, 
    bg = "white", res = NA, 
    type = c("cairo", "cairo-png", "Xlib", "quartz"))
hist(se)
dev.off()

write.csv(summary_dat, "summary.csv")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the for loop inside R (or use map/lapply functions).

You can build a function that make the two plots and summary file just for one file passed as paramater, and then name plots inside R function, for instance replace .gz by _1.png and _2.png for the two plots using `stringr::str_replace(filename_gz, '\\.gz', '_1\\.png)`

To list your *gz files which serve as index for loop, you can use `list.files()` R function.

So:

```
list_of_gz <- list.files(repo, pattern = '\\.gz')

your_plotting_function <- function(one_file){
   save_your_png_with_one_file_name # you can replace 
                                    # .gz by .png for instance 
                                    # programmatically
   return(summary) # for example
}

# for loop
for (f in list_of_gz){
  your_plotting_function(f)
}

# map
purrr::map(list_of_gz, your_plotting_function)
```